# Does backend web development mean REST API and MICROSERVICES development

Tags: rest, microservices, backend

Is the **backend** developers' job to create **rest api**s and **microservice**s ?

If not then what else the backend developers do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer would be, that a back-end developer does everything that a front-end developer does not. Back-end development would typically include building REST APIs, networking/system devops, database management, cloud infrastructure management, etc. Back-end would imply things are not seen by users but are necessary for projects to run, and front-end would imply the opposite; things are directly seen and interacted with by users.

A lot of developers are full-stack developers, or somewhere in between front-end and back-end developer. They do a little front-end, and a little back-end development as well.

Comment: what technologies/ skills do one need to know to be a cloud infrastructure architect ?

Comment: I would recommend starting with Amazon Web Services (AWS). Amazon offers certifications in AWS, and they have many tools/services that you can get familiar with.

Comment: and who gets paid the most among  REST API developer, devops, database admin and cloud infrastructure architect  :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have asked could be one part of the job. Backend developer could also be working on the Model and Controller in case of MVC architecture, incase it is a single monolithic application. Better get it clarified. :)